# Incorrect Date Format Display

Tags: asp.net, date, format

I'm using ASP.Net and I'm trying  to display a date in my webpage. However, it display the date like this /Date(1432500100000)/ instead of the usual date format.

Any idea why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you returning a JsonResult? Take the number and pass it to a Date constructor: `new Date(1432500100000)` on the JS side.

Comment: Please show an example of what you're attempting to do in code. The undesired output isn't enough by itself to help anyone diagnose this problem without guessing.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the confusion. Yes, I am returning JsonRsult. 
 @Calculuswhiz Sir, how can i do that?

Comment: @JayPee Can update your question to show a) the object you're serializing in the controller and b) what you're doing with the `JsonResult` in the View?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to show the date example you want to display, otherwise your date formats can always be displayed as follows:

```
ASP.NETControl = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
ASP.NETControl2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

This all depends on the format that you require. also, remember the date control has other properties like SPAN that can show date as a number including time

Comment: Hello sir, the dates that I want to display is for example: 2/23/2021.

Comment: You can reconstruct the date by splitting it into 3 variables, Year, Month, and Date
var YearInt =  DateString.Substring(6,4));
var MonthInt = DateString.Substring(1,1);
var dayInt = DateString.Substring(4,2);
after this split you can then  you can then concatenate the values into you ASP.NET Control to display for example
ASPControl.Text = dayInt + "/" +monthint+ "/" +YearInt